# Export from to PDF throws Internal Error: The export doesn't support one of the functionalities in this report

Tags: vb.net, pdf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm trying to export a report into a pdf file with vb.net but i get an "Internal exception: The export select doesn't supports one of the functionalities used on the report:"
I'm using a very simple code:

```
cr.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, stringPath)
```

I've already check if the path exists and permissions of the folder in wich i export my file and they're all correct. I've looked already on the internet for more solutions but it seems that i'm the only one with this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the font on my report. It seems that i was using a font not readable by VS2012. So i change it back to arial and things went rigth.